# Can we use a series of properties to determine integral operator $f \to \int_0^1 f d\mu $

Tags: integration, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, integral-operators

**Question:** Suppose there exists an operator $I: C^{\infty}(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ satisfying the following properties:

(1) $I (\chi_{(0,1)})=1$ ;

(2) $I(kf)=kI(f)$, where $k\in \mathbb R$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(0,1)$;

(3) $I(f+g)=I(f) + I(g)$, where $f,g\in C^{\infty}(0,1)$;

(4) $I(f)\le I(g)$, whenever $f\le g$ on $(0,1)$

Can we conclude that $I$ must be the integral operator $\int_0^1 d \mu$ for some measure $\mu$ on $(0,1)$?

**Note:** What if the property (3) is replaced by:

(3)'$I(f+g)\le I(f) + I(g)$, where $f,g\in C^{\infty}(0,1)$

Comment: The operator $I(f) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(i/n)$ satsify $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ for any $n$. For an even simpler example $I(f) = f(a)$ for any $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: You are right. But your example can be viewed as some different measures on $(0,1)$. Please see my question again, I have edited it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not hard to see that your properties imply that the functional is bounded and thus extends to a bounded positive (!) linear functional on $C ([0,1]) $. By the Riesz  representation theorem,  it follows that your function is given by integration against some probability measure. I don't know what happens if you consider (3'), but I doubt that it is still true.

Comment: Actually,  we have $-I (f+g)=I (-F + (-g))\leq I (-f)+I (-g)=-(I (f)+I (g)) $ which implies $I (f)+I (g)\leq I (f+g) $, so that your conditions with (3') imply (3).